# Google OAuth2 API JWS conformance

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid, openid-connect, jwe

Google currently exposes, at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs, the following certificate values

```
{
 "keys": [
  {
   "kty": "RSA",
   "alg": "RS256",
   "use": "sig",
   "kid": "90adc60c0f9f503265a5ebc2c404c88e59882083",
   "n": "u_EOLEKRMNuTA_UPh9R-LTQkF1TNGE6XRVbgvh081A5VtKNFe8b2CmoGvgrm_ochjX0robr8LwpOUSHO779yJANgvwuATHJ4SKYHzN2Gr0yBsC7MyL9CI_eXik4RGiNlEU6mgoy7GGnLtY5-A6OPo-I-4HEttP81LJrmSYh6Y2k=",
   "e": "AQAB"
  },
  {
   "kty": "RSA",
   "alg": "RS256",
   "use": "sig",
   "kid": "5886590f72b8e40668c55fa366c19efb2a22d635",
   "n": "x9mePRk3StM-Tg32S_E8OyBYD8uIHhPPa6U8jkHbpnRf2jEImk1ndIwIoJQCrHl1IsKpY1j81fyQKul0u1Frvb-LFGFVY3L7zSR4hnwzuU_05JtKZRfK-87Kj8JVMJbt34SKRmUitPH4QA23b6g-ORUMYjqWgNWufV6OPy8GYNE=",
   "e": "AQAB"
  }
 ]
}
```

I'm trying to access Google APIs using [oic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oic) and [jwkest](https://github.com/rohe/pyjwkest), and get the error

```
DeSerializationNotPossible: Not base64url encoded
```

The problem occurs because the `n` parameters of both keys end in a `=` character. IIUC, they should be Base64URL encoded according to [JSON Web Algorighms draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-algorithms-38#section-6.3.1.1), and Base64URL strips the `=` characters, according to the [JSON Web Signature draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-38#section-2).

Is this error in the Python libraries I'm using, or is this indeed Google not conforming to the specification? If the latter: where can I report it?

Comment: um wow.  Best place I have found to get some official type of technical response would be the Google Oauth2 community on Google+ https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/107137198518854169493 From what I have heard there isn't really a dev team for Oauth2 right now its considered stable. I haven't found any place a report issues.   try G+ someone there might be able to help, if not I can see if I can find someone to ping at google.

Comment: good find; I have not experienced problems with it so far because I use clients that have implemented a padding method that will not break on it; it certainly does not seem compliant to me

Comment: It turns out that the author of jwkest has now dropped the validity check from his implementation. So with the next release, the actual problem should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Google isn't compliant with (the now RFCs) [JWA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518) and [JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) in using regular base64 rather than base64url. However, I believe they've already been made aware of the issue and fixed it with a new version of the JWKS endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs, which has the same keys as v2 but encoded properly per spec. You should be able to consume the v3 endpoint with the libraries you're using.